# Subscribe to observable returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

So I have a service that uses a dictionary to store HTTP responses (maps an id to a specific URL).

```js
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class urlService {
  private map: Map<string, string>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.map = new Map<string, string>();
  }

  public getUrl(id: string): Observable<string> {
    if (this.map.has(id)) {
      return of(this.map.get(id));
    }

    this.http.get<any>(`...sampleURL...`)
    .subscribe((result) => {
      this.map.set(id, result.url);
      return of(this.map.get(id));
    });
  }
}
```

However, when I try to get this `url` from my app component, the logged value is `undefined`.

```js
this.urlService.getUrl(this.id).subscribe(
  url => console.log(url)
);
```

I suppose this is because in `urlService.getUrl()` I have a subscription returning an `Observable`. Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this issue?

I tried using `switchMap`, but that didn't seem to help.

```js
this.http.get<any>(`...sampleUrl...}`).pipe(
  switchMap(result => {
    this.map.set(id, result.url);
    return of(this.map.get(id));
  }))
.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correctly returning the `Observable` in the current `getUrl` method. It doesn't have any return value thus return `undefined`.

Instead, you should return `Observable` with the `map` rxjs operator.

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs';

public getUrl(id: string): Observable<string> {
  if (this.map.has(id)) {
    return of(this.map.get(id));
  }

  return this.http.get<any>(`...sampleURL...`)
      .pipe(
        map((result) => {
          this.map.set(id, result.url);

          return this.map.get(id); 
          // Or 
          // return result.url; 
        })
      );
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kctmpg?file=src/url.service.ts)

Comment: Oh I see, I was subscribing to the HTTP request and 'returning' something there, but that actually doesn't return anything from the `getUrl` method. Thank you!